# Cut integer as time into 15 minutes intervals

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate, chron

Time is in the format of integer, and it is without date. I tried to use package lubridate but it asks for both date and time.

I was not able to find an equivalent of seq() in package chron either.

The column looks like:

```
time
525
1526
756
2252
...
```

525 represents 5:25; 1526 represents 7:56.
And I'd like to have a table that counts frequency in each 15 mins interval; intervals are `00:00-00:15, 00:16-00:30, 00:31-00:45, 00:46-00:59, ..., 23:46-23:59`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert to `ITime` with `as.ITime` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
v2 <- as.ITime(sub("^(..)", "\\1:", sprintf('%04d:00', df1$time)))
table(cut(v2, breaks = 15))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(time = c(525, 1526, 756, 2252)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: sorry that I didn't specify: 5:25 represents 5:25:00. So the intervals should be 00:00:00-00:15:00, 00:16:00-00:30:00, 00:31:00-00:45:00, 00:46:00-00:59:00, ..., 23:46:00-23:59:00 (a total of 24*4=156 intervals). In your code, %H:%M is treated as %M:%S.

Comment: @Michelle i made the correction for 'v2', but the `cut` part breaks I am not sure.  Are you creating the breaks from another set of variable